# auto_ptr Traps and Pitfalls

Tags: c++, auto-ptr

Besides all the known benefits of using auto_ptrs, what are auto_ptr "worst-practices"?

1. Creating STL contrainers of auto_ptrs.
   auto_ptrs don't fulfill the 'CopyConstructable' requirement. See also Scott Meyer's  "Effective STL", item 8.
2. Creating auto_ptrs of arrays
   Upon destruction, auto_ptr's destructor uses 'delete' (and never 'delete[]') to destroy the owned object, so this code yields undefined behavior:
   auto_ptr api(new int[42]);
3. Not taking care of copy-ctor and op= in a class using auto_ptr members.
   One might naively think that by using auto_ptr members one doesn't need to implement the copy constructor/assignment operator for a class. However, even a single auto_ptr member 'poisons' a class (i. e. violates the 'CopyConstructable' and 'Assignable' requirements). Objects of such classes would be partly damaged during the copy/assignment operation.

Are there even more auto_ptr pitfalls?

Comment: Also, `auto_ptr` will be deprecated in the next C++ standard (which Sutter hopes will be officially voted on after March 2011 (http://herbsutter.com/2010/08/28/trip-report-august-2010-iso-c-standards-meeting/), thus becoming C++0B for us die-hards).  If you've got `unique_ptr`, use it instead.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if this is a trap/pitfall, but it's certainly less than obvious:

- A const auto_ptr cannot have its ownership of the contained pointer transferred

In other words:

```
const auto_ptr<Foo> ap(new Foo());
auto_ptr<Foo> ap2;

ap2 = ap; // Not legal!
```

This is in fact quite *useful* if you want to take an auto_ptr argument and guarantee that you won't be taking ownership of the contained pointer, but it can also be surprising if you expect a `const auto_ptr<Foo>` to behave like a `Foo const*`.